# javascript return false or preventDefault is not working

Tags: javascript

I know this has to be something obvious, but even after following instructions elsewhere, I'm getting the same result.

The alert on the JavaScript call comes up, but after clicking okay, it continues to submit the form.

```
function validateBadEmail(inputText)
{
    var mailformat = /.ru$/
    if(inputText.value.match(mailformat))
    {
        alert("This is not an accepted email address");
        inputText.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm calling it:

```
<input type="button" id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-blue btn-less-padding" name="submit-btn" value="<?= $txt_submit_btn; ?>" tabindex="0" onclick="return validateBadEmail(document.the_form.email)"/>
```

I have tried this by using `return false` instead of `preventDefault` but that's having the same effect.

If I change the `onclick` to `onsubmit` it doesn't even call the javascript at all.

**Edit:**   clearly preventDefault is the wrong way, but if I try to do it this way, I'm still getting the same results

```
function validateBadEmail(inputText)
{
    var mailformat = /.ru$/
    if(inputText.value.match(mailformat))
    {
        alert("This is not an accepted email address");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `inputText` is not an Event.  `preventDefault()` is an Event method.  Returning false should do the trick.  Show us the logic that you had when you tried to return false.

Comment: You could also attach the button press function to the onSubmit of the parent form element itself instead of the button. Adding a preventDefault to that submit event would do the same

Comment: onsubmit is a form attribute. cannot be set on buttons

Comment: "If I change the onclick to onsubmit it doesn't even call the javascript at all." That is because a button does not have a submit event.

Comment: If you are just validating with a reg exp, just use pattern attribute with required.

Comment: so, I'm trying to do this with onclick and return false, but that's not preventing the form from submitting..

Comment: My guess is you have an error.... Does the alert appear? What does your form look like?

Comment: Also `<input type="button"` is not a submit button so unsure how it would submit the form.

Comment: I'm getting that at this point.  so does anyone have any suggestions for how to make this work?  I tried changing the button into input type="submit" but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Show the form....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Your `validateBadEmail` function is missing a `return` instruction. Set one return value  for either IF case.

## EDIT

Second: Validating input data must be done in the `onsubmit` event handler of the containing FORM. Handling `onclick` events in the input controls won't prevent the form being sumbitted.

Comment: okay, but as I mentioned, when I change it to onsubmit, the javascript doesn't get triggered at all.   Is it because it is a button?   If that's the case, how do I get it to trigger.  Or should I place the code into the form element instead?   (I'm confusing the heck out of myself)

Comment: Exactly: Set the `onsubmit` within the FORM element, not into the INPUTs or BUTTONs. A submission is an action which affects the whole FORM.